# How to work with extra int parameter in LINQ Where()

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, where-clause, func

Please note that it's not a question about what [delegates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) are in general. Also, I've seen the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx) without getting any wiser.

In LINQ, I can use something like this.

```
using(Model model = new Model())
{
   return model.Things
               .Where(thing => thing.IsGood);
}
```

I can see that the return type (the left object of the operator) is of type `Thing` and the condition (the right object of the operator) is of type `bool`. Intellisense tells me that I can pick from these two and I was confused by the second one.

```
Func<Thing, bool>  
Func<Thing, int, bool>
```

I'm assuming that the lambda operator's just a syntactic sugar for the actual call. Is that correct? If so, what is that integer doing there and how do I specify it?

Comment: Documentation of [Where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx) answers all your questions!

Comment: It is an index of the element in loop. Look at the example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: It allows you to see the index of the item currently being processed in the where. Simple as that.

Comment: @RahulSingh It really doesn't. I've edited the question. Not saying it's not there. I'm saying that I've seen it and I have the same question still...

Answer (score 4):

From the [docs for this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418(v=vs.110).aspx):

> *predicate*
>
> Type: `System.Func<TSource, Int32, Boolean>`
>
> A function to test each source element for a condition; the second parameter of the function represents the index of the source element.

The integer is, as this suggests, the index of the element.

So,

```
var everyTwo = input.Where((c, i) => i % 2 == 0);
```

Returns only every second element, for example. The documentation linked above has a slightly more complex example of a use-case that involves both parameters.

I'm not sure if this was just a typo, but the docs you linked to appear to be for the overload that does not contain this parameter, which might explain why you couldn't find an explanation for it.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments already, documentation states that the second overlod:-

> Filters a sequence of values based on a predicate. Each element's
>   index is used in the logic of the predicate function.

And here is the [reference code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,9463aefcdc7c766f) which I guess will make clear things to you:-

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
                                                   Func<TSource, int, bool> predicate) 
{
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    if (predicate == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("predicate");
    return WhereIterator<TSource>(source, predicate);
}

static IEnumerable<TSource> WhereIterator<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
                                                   Func<TSource, int, bool> predicate) 
{
   int index = -1;
   foreach (TSource element in source) {
       checked { index++; }
       if (predicate(element, index)) yield return element;
   }
}
```

You can see how index which we provide is used in the `foreach` statement. Thus we can use the predicate as:-

```
.Where((thing, index) => thing.SomeIntProperty <= index * 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

To illustrate with an example rather than simply quote the MSDN help page:

Take this code:

```
var list = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" }
var index = 0;
foreach (var item in list)
{
    if (item == "b" && index == 1) {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
    index++;
}
```

becomes

```
var list = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" }

var items = list.Where((item, index) => item == "b" && index == 1)

foreach (var item in items) {
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

(you could use other linq commands for the writeline etc, this is to illustrate the `Where`)

Comment: Very useful to show the foreach version to compare with the LINQ version.  Clever idea. +1

Answer (score 1):

As it says in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Filters a sequence of values based on a predicate. Each element's
>   index is used in the logic of the predicate function.

When you need this? For example, may be you need all elements which has even index:

```
return model.Things
    .Where((thing, index) => index % 2 == 0);
```

Also, in the future you cand find and learn such things more depply using [this web site](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/) which offers us `.net` source code. For example, here is the implementation of the overlaod of the `Where()` method:

```
 public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, int, bool> predicate) {
            if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
            if (predicate == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("predicate");
            return WhereIterator<TSource>(source, predicate);
        }
```

We can see that it returns `WhereIterator` method:

```
static IEnumerable<TSource> WhereIterator<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, int, bool> predicate) {
            int index = -1;
            foreach (TSource element in source) {
                checked { index++; }
                if (predicate(element, index)) yield return element;
            }
        }
```

We can see that actually Linq uses `foreach` loop, and gets index of the current element by incrementing `index` variable by one.

Answer (score 0):

There are two MSDN articles on *Where*. [The one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that you linked to and [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418(v=vs.110).aspx).

The syntax for usage would be as follows.

```
using(Model model = new Model())
{
  return model.Things
    .Where((thing, counter) => thing.IsGood < counter);
}
```

As you see it makes little sense in **this** particular case and I've never needed to use it. Nevertheless, if the need arises, it's there. You can find an example at the link provided.